# Cut after the closest word boundary after specific length

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Input**

```
<items>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy tempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy<br/>tempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor magna aliquyam erat</b>. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor <i>magna</i> aliquyam erat</b>. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</item>
</items>
```

**Requirements**

- "Cut" **after** the closest word after a specific length, e.g. 25 characters (incl. whitespaces)
- All `nodes()` **before** that position are untouched
- All `*` **after** that position get a attribute `foo="bar"`
- All `text()` **after** that position are processed by a `template with mode='xy'` (this template will uglify the text); the template wraps all adjacent `text()`-nodes in a `<o foo="bar">` + itself as '#'
- IF `text()`-nodes are in a particial readable/uglified `*`, these `text()`-nodes are wrapped within a new element `<o foo="bar">` [see item[4] => "aliquyam erat"] + itself as '#'
- IF `string-length(text()) le $visibleChars` THEN nothing happens

**Output**

```
<!-- middle of word "temppor" -->
<xsl:variable name="visibleChars" select="number(48)"/>
<items>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy tempor<o foo="bar"> #</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy<br/>tempor<o foo="bar"> #</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor<o foo="bar">#</o></b><o foo="bar">#</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor <i foo="bar">#</i><o foo="bar"> #</o></b><o foo="bar">#</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</item>
</items>
```

**Failed pseudo xslt**

```
<xsl:templates match="item">
  WHEN count(text()) eq count(node())
  THEN
     Create a $temp of <item> AND insert a <cut/> at position ($visibleChars + CharsTillNextDelimiter)
     <!-- chars to stay visible -->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp/text()[following-sibling::cut]"/>
     <!-- chars to uglify -->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp/text()[preceding-sibling::cut]" mode="xy"/>

  WHEN (*)
  THEN
     NoIDEAToTackleMixedContentFields

...
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="xy">

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
...
```

I don't have a running minified xslt, nevertheless someone might show me a way to fulfill the requirements. Any help is appreciated and I hope I covered all possible circumstances in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to insert the `cut` element and to then process the modified `item` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="length" select="48"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:escape-for-regex" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>

        <xsl:sequence
            select="
                replace($arg,
                '(\.|\[|\]|\\|\||\-|\^|\$|\?|\*|\+|\{|\}|\(|\))', '\\$1')
                "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[string-length() gt $length]">
        <xsl:variable name="head" as="xs:string" select="substring(., 1, $length)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="head-pattern" as="xs:string"
            select="concat('^', functx:escape-for-regex($head), '\S*')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text-to-cut" as="text()"
            select="descendant::text()[matches(string-join((preceding::text()[. >> current()], .), ''), $head-pattern)][1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="splitted-text" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$text-to-cut"
                regex="{if ($text-to-cut is (current()//text())[1]) then $head-pattern else '^\S+'}">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="modified-copy" as="element(item)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="modify">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text-to-cut" as="text()" select="$text-to-cut"
                        tunnel="yes"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="splitted-text" as="xs:string*" select="$splitted-text"
                        tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message select="'modified-copy', $modified-copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$modified-copy" mode="cut"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item//text()" mode="modify">
        <xsl:param name="text-to-cut" as="text()" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:param name="splitted-text" as="xs:string*" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". is $text-to-cut">
                <xsl:value-of select="$splitted-text[1]"/>
                <cut/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$splitted-text[2]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cut" mode="cut"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::cut]" mode="cut">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="foo">bar</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[preceding::cut]" mode="cut">
        <o foo="bar">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </o>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I get for your input is not quite what you posted but close so I hope you can adapt that:

```
<items>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy tempor<o foo="bar"> # # #. # # #.</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy<br/>tempor<o foo="bar"> # # #. # # #.</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor<o foo="bar"> # # #</o></b><o foo="bar">. # # #.</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy <b>tempor<o foo="bar"> </o><i foo="bar"><o foo="bar">#</o></i><o foo="bar"> # #</o></b><o foo="bar">. # # #.</o></item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</item>
</items>
```

Comment: This is a heavy regex based solution (because it's a heavy based string manipulation question), but i will give it a try later on. thanks for taking time for solving.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way is to become string with only one common special character to eliminate all others as ' .,', please have a look below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >    
<xsl:output method="xml" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />    
<xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <item>
                <xsl:variable name="main.string" select="."/>
                <!--transform string with only one delimiter-->
                <xsl:variable name="format.string" select="translate(normalize-space($main.string), ' ,.', '|')"/>
                <!--get string till 25th character-->
                <xsl:variable name="format.limit.string" select="substring(normalize-space($main.string), 0, 24)"/>
                <!--get 25th character-->
                <xsl:variable name="format.last.char" select="translate($format.limit.string, substring($format.limit.string, 0, 23), '')"/>      
                <!--check if the 25th character is delimiter or part of the word-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$format.last.char = '|'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space($format.limit.string), 0, 23)"/>
                        <xsl:element name="o">
                        <xsl:attribute name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="'bar'"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($main.string, 24, string-length($main.string))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--if cut in the middle of the word then rest part will be added-->
                        <xsl:variable name="final.string" select="concat($format.limit.string, substring-before(substring($format.string, 24, string-length($format.string)), '|'))"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$final.string"/>                        
                        <xsl:element name="o">
                        <xsl:attribute name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="'bar'"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($main.string, string-length($final.string)+1, string-length($main.string))"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>        
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </items>            
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a result you will have your limitation with 25 chars (till the word) - other cosmetic things are possible to add by concat function in my code:

```
<items>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<o foo="bar"/>, sed diam nonumy tempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<o foo="bar"/>, sed diam nonumytempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<o foo="bar"/>, sed diam nonumy tempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<o foo="bar"/>, sed diam nonumy tempor magna aliquyam erat. Ssed diam voluptua.</item>
    <item>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<o foo="bar"/>.</item>
</items>
```

Hope it will help.